# Potting Dygraph for huge data in 20 min interval

Tags: r

I am new to R and I was trying to plot dygraph for time series of 2014-09-02 12:00:00 to 2014-12-12 11:40:00. The data was taken every 20 min. My data looks like the following.

```
Date                Temp2   Temp3
9/1/2014 12:20:00   22.7    22.7
9/1/2014 12:40:00   22.5    22.8
9/1/2014 12:20:00   22.4    22.9
9/1/2014 01:00:00   22.3    22.9
9/1/2014 01:20:00   22.2    22.9
9/1/2014 01:40:00   22.2    22.9
9/1/2014 02:00:00   22.1    23
```

The data continued for four months. The following is the code I have tried but fail to succeed.

```
## My data frame(Data) contains 7347 rows.
data1<-rnorm(Data`)
# The data collected every 20 min (72 times/day)

d1<-seq(as.POSIXct("2014-09-02 12:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2014-12-12 11:40:00"), by=72)

 df <- data.frame(cbind(d1, data1))
```

## time series

```
ts1<-ts(df[,2:3], start=0,end=101*24,frequency=60/20)

dygraph(df) %>% dyRangeSelector()
    dygraph(ts1) %>% dyRangeSelector()
    dygraph(Temp2) %>% dyRangeSelector()
    dygraph(Tem3) %>% dyRangeSelector()
```

I appreciate any help.

Selam

Comment: Why have you tagged this JavaScript if its an R question?

Comment: Hey Selam, don't you need  to use only ts in dygraphs instead of starting with a data.frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you might have been thinking a bit way too hard. Once you have a time series object, you use that to draw a graphic. You may want to provide a reproducible data to clarify your point, if necessary.

```
library(data.table)
library(dygraphs)

set.seed(111)
mydf <- data.frame(Date = seq(from = as.POSIXct("2014-09-02 12:00:00", tz = "UTC"),
                              to = as.POSIXct("2014-09-02 14:00:00", tz = "UTC"), by = 1200),
                   Temp2 = sample.int(40, size = 7),
                   Temp3 = sample.int(20, size = 7))

#                 Date Temp2 Temp3
#1 2014-09-02 12:00:00    24    11
#2 2014-09-02 12:20:00    29     9
#3 2014-09-02 12:40:00    15     2
#4 2014-09-02 13:00:00    20    10
#5 2014-09-02 13:20:00    14    17
#6 2014-09-02 13:40:00    38    18
#7 2014-09-02 14:00:00     1     1

# Create a time series object
as.xts.data.table(setDT(mydf)) -> foo

# Draw a figure 
dygraph(foo)
```

[image]

```
dygraph(foo) %>% dyRangeSelector()
```

[image]

Comment: many thanks fro your help. Let me clarify my question in detail.I have temperature data taken by datalogger ever 20min from 9/2/2014 0:00 to 12/12/2014 23:40(month.day.year.hour.minute order).My CSV data has 7347 rows and 3 columns(Date, Temp2 and Temp3). As a beginner, I couldn't understand some the codes you used in the sample above. What by=1200 indicate for? I am not clear with Temp2 = sample.int(40, size = 7),Temp3 = sample.int(20, size = 7))
 Is that time interval for each observation? The time interval for both was the same which is 20min. The following is  code I used

Comment: @Selam What you mentioned is all about my sample data. So you do not have to worry about anything. You want to make sure that you use a time series object when you use dfgraph. In your code, `df` is just a data frame. It is not a time series object.

Comment: I tried to plot using the sample code and got error.
selam_final <- read.csv("C:/Users/Selamawit/Desktop/selam.csv")
selam_final<- as.data.frame(selam_final  , header=True)
library(dygraphs)
library(data.table)
set.seed(111)
mydf <- data.frame(Date = seq(from = as.POSIXct("9-2-2014 0:00", tz = "UTC"),to = as.POSIXct("12-12-2014 23:40", tz = "UTC"), by = 1200),Temp2 = sample.int(40, size = 7347),Temp3 = sample.int(20, size = 7347), data=selam_final)
 
Error in sample.int(40, size = 7347) : cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'

Comment: @Selam When you import your data with read.csv, you already have a data frame. I imagine you have three columns as you mentioned. Yet, `selam_final` is just a data frame. You need to convert that to a time series object. I think this is why you used `ts()`, no? In my sample data, I had a data frame as `mydf`. Then, I converted it to a data.table object. Then, I converted it to a time series object with `as.xts.data.table()`. You are mixing your data with my sample data. You just want to focus on your own data.

Comment: Thank you! I used the above code and got  Error in sample.int(40, size = 7347) cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'. Can you help me?

Comment: @Selam If you want to know `sample.int()`, Type `?sample.int` in your R console. You can see more information. The reason why get the error message is that you tried to create 7347 integers. But other variables do not have exact the same amount. Reading what you wrote, I think you need to study some basic R things before you move on. I gotta go now, but I will leave one more thing for you. `sample.int(40, size = 7` means choose 7 random numbers between 1 and 40. I needed 7 numbers because I have 7 dates. You need a same length for all variables. Otherwise, you cannot create a data frame.

Comment: @Selam I am glad to hear that! Please read [**THIS**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).